# How to read a kernel module (/dev) file from user space C

Tags: c, file-io, linux-kernel

In my kernel module the read function is as follows:

```
ssize_t aes_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) { 

  unsigned long aes_reg[4];
  aes_reg[0] = leon_load_reg(output_mem_loc);
  aes_reg[1] = leon_load_reg(output_mem_loc+4);
  aes_reg[2] = leon_load_reg(output_mem_loc+8);
  aes_reg[3] = leon_load_reg(output_mem_loc+12);
  copy_to_user(buf, (char *)aes_reg, 16);
  ....
```

And it appears in the kernel module that `buf` is being set properly. On the user space side I have written this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE *fpaes;
    char *str;
    int buf[4];

    fpaes = fopen("/dev/aes", "r");
    fread(str, 16, 1, fpaes);
    p_long = (unsigned long *)str;
    ....
```

But `str` is not being updated with the values I expect. Am I allowed to do an `fread` in this way or am I way off?

Comment: This isn't causing your problem, but not that it's generally preferable to directly call the system calls [`read(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) et al instead of going through the stdio layer, since stdio buffers reads and writes by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str` is not initialized in your program. Accessing `*str` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yep, I must have missed that. Thanks.